# How to play audio on the click of html page link>

Tags: html

This is what I got so far:

```
<audio id="player" src="../media/Click.mp3"></audio>

<div>
    <a href="index.html" onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Home</a>
</div>
```

Instead of playing the audio first and then going on to the page, it just goes to the next page. What do I need to change? If I change the a href to # instead of index.html it will play the audio.

Comment: try changing it to <a href="#"....> I think that will do the trick.

Comment: What if I want it to go to another HTML page and not just index?

Comment: Then you need to: 1. clarify your question, and 2. probably open the player in another window since it's on the page you are trying to leave.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally put a delay on the hyperlink. For example, a 5 second delay - so that when the button is clicked, the audio would play (during the delay) and then take the person to the link specified.

For example:

```
<html>
<head>

<!-- This is where the delay is specified -->
<script>
function delay (URL) {
    setTimeout( function() { window.location = URL }, 5000 );
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- This is where the audio file is specified -->
<audio id="player" src="../media/Click.mp3"></audio>

<!-- The hyperlink is specified via the javascript delay -->
<div>
    <a href="javascript:delay('/index.html')" onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Home</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please note: In the example above, the delay is set to 5 seconds (`5000` milliseconds). This can be changed according to the amount of time you want the user to hear the audio. Also, in the `href`, change the `/index.html` to the destination page, but ensure that the URL is specified within the apostrophes, e.g. `'URL'`.

Hope this helps.